# Autowired instance is null and causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, autowired

In the first case the autowired cartService works fine, but I don't know why in the second case when I want to use the autowired cartService(in an another class) I get null as its value.
Here is a part of the source:

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CartRepository extends JpaRepository<Cart, Integer> {
    Cart findById(int id);
}
```

Service:

```
public interface CartService{

    Iterable<Cart> getAllCart();
    Cart getCart(int id);
    void save(Cart cart);
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
@Service
public class CartServiceImpl implements CartService{

    @Autowired
    CartRepository cartRepository;

    @Override
    public Iterable<Cart> getAllCart() {
        return cartRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Cart getCart(int id) {
        return cartRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Cart cart) {
        cartRepository.saveAndFlush(cart);
    }
}


@Component
public class ColumnLay extends VerticalLayout {

    @Autowired
    CartService cartService;

    //...some code...cartService works fine
}
```

UI class

```
@Route("purchase")
@Component
@UIScope
public class Purchase extends VerticalLayout {

    @Autowired
    CartService cartService;

    //here when I use cartService I get null
    //some code goes here
}
```

Comment: `@SpringComponent`? Did you mean `@Service` which is a specialization of `@Component`? --- And you should remove `@Service` from the interface, since `@Service` / `@Component` are for annotating the implementation class.

Comment: ColumnLay is not a Spring bean. That's why it is not handled in Application Context where autowiring takes place.

Comment: Of course, you are right, I just tried it and I left it accidentally

Comment: Hua I tried, but still null, I put @Component to ColumnLay...

Comment: Remove the @Service from `CartService` interface.replace @SpringComponent with @Service on `CartServiceImpl`. This should be all.

Comment: @raviiii1 Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

You did not show where in the Purchase class you happen to get a NullPointerException, but I suspect that it happens in the constructor, because that would make perfect sense.

Autowiring happens after the construction of an object. Therefore, your autowired cartService is null in your constructor. If there is a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`, then this is called after the autowiring - your service will be there then.

Or you could switch from field injection to constructor injection. By using constructor injection, the cartService will be available in the constructor already.

```
@Route("purchase")
@Component
@UIScope
public class Purchase extends VerticalLayout {

    // no annotation here!
    CartService cartService;

    //this way cartService is not null in constructor
    @Autowired
    public Purchase(CartService cartService){
        this.cartService = cartService;
    }
}
```

Comment: Originally I made the first way you advised, and I also tried the second way with constructor injection, but none of these worked, still get the null...Any ideas?

Comment: was my assumption correct that the nullPointerException is happening in the constructor though?

Comment: No, I have another method within the class, there is happening

Comment: Now I get null in both classes.